# Video tag on react with create-react-app project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, create-react-app

I am having problem adding a local video to my project as

```
<video src={import(src/assets/abc.mp4)} type="video/mp4"/>
```

I have researched and found out about

> web pack configuration

to make this possible but i can't figure out how to introduce it to create-react-app project.

I can't go cloud hosting for my videos because i need it on mobile version as well.please can anyone help?

Comment: Do you know what changes you need to do to the webpack configuration?

Comment: can you share your webpack?

Comment: @AftabKhan since im not using webpack manually i can't find a way to configure, since react-script is running the web pack tasks inside. so if webpack config is the solution i should start by trying to add a config file which works with react-scripts. can you please guide me from there to my original issue which is local video play on my project?

Comment: @VikramSaini i havent tried webpack config since i can't find a way to hack the create-react-app behavior if it's the only way then i am wiling to try

Comment: My question was more around, do you know how to work with webpack configurations. You can get all the project dependencies under your project folder by running `npm run eject`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax you’re trying to use (dynamic `import()`) is for [code splitting](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#code-splitting), not for [adding files](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files).
I’m not sure why you were looking for Webpack configuration, as this is supported out of the box.

Please follow the [official documentation](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files) that explains how to import assets:

```
// Assuming abc.mp4 is in the same folder as this component
import myVideo from './abc.mp4';
// This will become a string with the path to the video at build time

// Your component definition
export default function MyComponent() {
  return <video src={myVideo} type="video/mp4" />;
}
```

Comment: This works for images just fine, but admittedly I'm having trouble doing the same for videos. The video never loads using this code, although the video url is valid and loads if placed in the browser by itself. Has anyone had problems with that?

Comment: It may just be that you don't have the correct format for the browser. You may need `.ogv` format for FF. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

in `react-app-env.d.ts` add:

```js
declare module '*.mp4' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

Example of use:

```
import styles from './demo.module.scss';
import Video from './demo.mp4';


export default function Demo() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.demoWrapper}>
            <div className={styles.demoContainer}>
                <video controls>
                    <source src={Video} type="video/mp4"/>
                </video>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```