# Local video will not load - Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I can't get a simple video to load/play, so I decided to try looking at the webpack file and it seems fine. The code is below.

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');

const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
const host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const publicPath = `${protocol}://${host}:${port}/`;

const publicUrl = '';
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: [
        require.resolve('./polyfills'),
        require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + `?${publicPath}`,
        require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
        paths.appIndexJs,
    ],
    output: {
        pathinfo: true,
        filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
        publicPath: publicPath,
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
            path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
            process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
        ),
        extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        },
        plugins: [
            new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
        ],
    },
    module: {
        strictExportPresence: true,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                use: [
                    {
                        options: {
                            formatter: eslintFormatter,
                            eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),  
                        },
                        loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
                    },
                ],
                include: paths.appSrc,
            },
            {
                oneOf: [
                    {
                        test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
                        loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
                        options: {
                            limit: 10000,
                            name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
                        include: paths.appSrc,
                        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
                        options: {
                            cacheDirectory: true,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.css$/,
                        use: [
                            require.resolve('style-loader'),
                            {
                                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                                options: {
                                    importLoaders: 1,
                                },
                            },
                            {
                                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                                options: {
                                    ident: 'postcss',
                                    plugins: () => [
                                        require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                                        autoprefixer({
                                            browsers: [
                                                '>1%',
                                                'last 4 versions',
                                                'Firefox ESR',
                                                'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                                            ],
                                            flexbox: 'no-2009',
                                        }),
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.(html)$/,
                        loader: require.resolve('html-loader'),
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.mp4$/,
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                                options: {
                                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                                }  
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
                        loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                        options: {
                            name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    ],
    node: {
        dgram: 'empty',
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty',
        child_process: 'empty',
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
    target: 'node-webkit',
};
```

This is my App.js below. I took out everything that doesn't matter. It's a simple call to an mp4 file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { curious } from '@curi/react';
import AttractLoop from '../../assets/videos/video.mp4';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app-container">
                <div className="attract-loop">
                    <video width="1080" height="1920">
                        <source src={ AttractLoop } type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default curious(App);
```

And here's a screenshot of my code inspector:

[image]

**Update 1**

I'm even trying to use this code from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928397/video-tag-on-react-with-create-react-app-project):

```
<video width="1080" height="1920" autoPlay loop src={ AttractLoop } type="video/mp4" />
```

**Update 2**

I downloaded the example [Big Buck Bunny vide](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html)o to rule out that my video was encoded incorrectly. Getting the same result, a blank page.

Comment: My first guess would be to drop the `static`. I assume that's part of your `output.publicPath` & `output.path`, so you shouldn't need it.

However, that's a total shot in the dark. Hard to say exactly without seeing the rest of your setup. If that's not the issue, can you please share the rest of your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: Edited the question to include the whole file

Comment: Hmm, your config looks OK at first glance. Can you check out two things for me? First, ensure that after you run webpack that the mp4 file is actually output to your `static/media` directory. Second, open up your bundle (I recommend Notepad++ for this if you're on windows as it handles large files extremely well) and search for the name of that mp4 file. Share that block of code here if that doesn't give you enough info to figure this out.

Comment: I don't see the mp4 inside bundle.js. I'm importing it to my class like so: `import carHomeToTopVideo from '../../assets/videos/_view_home_to_top.mp4';` and the correct url is showing in the video tag, showing as `localhost:3000/static/media/_view_home_to_top.mp4`. If I take the localhost link from the inspector and place it directly in the browser, the video plays. Any ideas?

Comment: It would appear your issue is not with your bundling process then, but with your app. Can you share some of the code that's relevant to playing the video?

Comment: I added the code calling my video file. I tried commenting out everything on my dev machine and got the simplest form of my page...one static video file that should run on load, and I only see the video's container, but not the video. No dev tools errors or anything warnings.

Comment: @JonnyAsmar Also with this simplified code, I do see the mp4 in my `bundle.js`. Any clue why the video still won't load?

Comment: Hmm, good thinking stripping it down -- what does your entire video tag look like? And can you access the video directly if you grab the source that's output in that video tag?

Comment: Ah -- are you using express as a server? If your static directory is `static`, you won't need it in the url, so it would just be `localhost:3000/media/ads_attract...`

Comment: This is a result of the way your webpack config is set up -- I'll post an answer in a moment with the proper changes in a minute.

Comment: @MartavisP. What kind an error shows on browser console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to place the answer to the real issue, although @Jonny had some good webpack changes that should help others.

My Create React App is mixed with Nw.js, which is a platform that allows users to create exe files from their projects. I found out from https://github.com/naviapps/create-nw-react-app/issues/6 that NW.js does not allow mp4s by default so I needed to either configure my project settings to accept them or change the format of my video to ogv (or others).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `webpack.config.js` is set up to output your media to a static directory. With ExpressJS, the static directory that you define should not be used in the public path. That path maps to the root of your public path. To fix this problem, you need to tweak your `webpack.config.js` to still output to this static directory, but not write it to the filename when its loaded with file-loader. Try something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + `?${publicPath}`,
    require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    paths.appIndexJs,
  ],
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].chunk.js',
    // double check that this has it's backslashes in the right place
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, publicPath + '/static'),
    publicPath: publicPath',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web',
    },
    plugins: [
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              //name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              name: 'media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(html)$/,
            loader: require.resolve('html-loader'),
          },
          {
            test: /\.mp4$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
                options: {
                  //name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                  name: 'media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            exclude: [/\.js$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              //name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              name: 'media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  ],
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  target: 'node-webkit',
};
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. Adding the changes (taking out static and adding the path to output) just made the server break. But this did make me dig in more. Would webpackDevServer have anything to do with this?

Comment: There could be something wrong with your config -- I don't personally use webpack-dev-server and prefer to stay away from it, but there could be a problem there. Basically, there are a few things you need to ensure happen: 1. Your assets are output to a directory you expect. 2. That directory is made public/static by your server. 3. Your code is referencing the correct url that points to that public/static directory. Is it possible you could trim this down and share it over github (so I could commit to it to show diffs)? I wouldn't mind taking a closer look in my env if it can help.

Comment: I would love and really appreciate the help! I have a lot of code so the easiest thing may be to install Create NW React App (https://github.com/naviapps/create-nw-react-app), eject it, then download the Big Buck Bunny video (http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html), place it locally, then use the code above to call the video on `App.js`.

I hadn't touched the config files before having issues so everything resembled a clean install.

Comment: hmmm -- looks like create-nw-react-app isn't linux compat :( think you could spin one up, eject it, and toss it up on github?

Comment: Thanks for really trying to help me on this! I ended up getting the real answer for this, but I believe your answer can help someone else who might be having webpack issues which is why you get the bounty. I got the real answer from the github of the project. Apparently, Nw.js (which is mixed with Create React App) does not allow mp4s by default, so I need to configure it to do so or change my video format to ogv.
https://github.com/naviapps/create-nw-react-app/issues/6

Comment: Oh man -- that must have been a fun limitation to dig up! Thank you for awarding the bounty at any rate. I do hope my solution can help some other folks :)